# Fabric Crashlytics showing "Release x.x.x Needs Investigation"

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

We simulated 3 test crashes on the device with out debugger. We can see the count of crashes but we couldn't see the reports on the dashboard.

It says "Release x.x.x needs investigation" under the Latest Release section.
It says "Investigation recommended" under the Top Builds section.

Please find the attached screenshot for more reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Naveen, Mike from Fabric here. Please email into support(at)fabric(dot)io with your app's bundle id so we can dive in more.

Comment: Thanks Mike, just sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. We experienced a data [loss](http://status.fabric.io/incidents/0hf9twr1rb74) from 8am Oct 3rd, through 10am Oct, 4th that affected new builds and releases. This only affected iOS, NDK, macOS, and tvOS apps that had a new release or build during this time (approximately 10% of crashes). Apologies for the issue.